# Changing data of UIPickerView Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I was searching very much, but i did not find an answer for my question.
My app should change the data of one picker after the other picker was changed.

As you can see, in the titleForRow method, I want to set the data and I also know that this method is just called once, but I just do not know where and also how I should do it then.

I think, on the didSelectRow method I could set the data, too, but there I do not have a gleam how I should do it.

Here is my code, I hope this is helpful.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource { 
    var x = 0 
    @IBOutlet weak var leaguePicker: UIPickerView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var clubPicker: UIPickerView! 
    let league = ["Bundesliga", "Premier League"] 
    let club = [["ManCity", "Arsenal"],["Bayern", "Dortmund"]] 

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        leaguePicker.delegate = self 
        leaguePicker.dataSource = self 
        clubPicker.delegate = self 
        clubPicker.dataSource = self 
    } 

    func numberOfComponents(in picker: UIPickerView) -> Int { 
        return 1 
    } 

    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int 
    { 
        switch (picker){ 
            case leaguePicker: 
                return league.count 
            case clubPicker: 
                return club.count 
            default: 
                return 1 
        } 
    } 

    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { 
        switch (picker){ 
            case leaguePicker: 
                return league[row] 
            case clubPicker: 
                if (x==0){ 
                    print("titleForRow call.. x=0") 
                    return club[0][row] 
                    // this is just happening at the beginning
                } else { 
                    print("titleForRow call.. x=1") 
                    return club[1][row] 
                    // this does not happen 
                } 
            default: return "an error occurred" 
        } 
    } 

    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) 
    { 
        if (picker == leaguePicker) {
             if (row==0){ 
                //clubPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true) 
                x=0 
            } else { 
            x=1 // this call is working
            //clubPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true) 
            } 
        } 
    picker.reloadAllComponents() 
    //this does not lead to call titleForRow 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reload the 2nd picker when the value in the 1st picker changes.

```
func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    if (picker == leaguePicker) {
        x = row
        clubPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

You also need to fix the `numberOfRowsInComponent`:

```
func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int 
{ 
    switch (picker){ 
        case leaguePicker: 
            return league.count 
        case clubPicker: 
            return club[x].count 
        default: 
            return 1 
    } 
}
```

And your `titleForRow` can be simplified:

```
func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { 
    switch (picker){ 
        case leaguePicker: 
            return league[row] 
        case clubPicker: 
            return club[x][row] 
        default: return "an error occurred" 
    } 
}
```

I also suggest you renamed your `x` variable to something more useful such as `selectedLeague`.